# How to center text in a circle within a list?

Tags: html, css, geometry

I am trying to make some sort of a "2 option choice game" by using two circles as buttons. Within the circle there should be a text, which is centered and does not stick out from the circle. But, when the text is too large, it sticks out underneath the circle.

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
<h1>Choose</h1>
</header>

<ul>
    <li>Read a book and lay on bed the whole day</li>
    <li>Go outside and ride a bycicle with friends</li>
</ul>

</body>

CSS:

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'oswalditalic';
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 0;
}
ul{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}


ul li{
    font-family: 'oswalditalic';
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:15px 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;

    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;

    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius:50%;

    background-color: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sf3dquLs/

Comment: Non programming-related suggestion: bycicle should be bicycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the value of the `line-height` to vertically center content. It works when there's one line but with two or more lines, it apply the 300px line-height and it is too much.

You can use `display:table-cell` combined with `vertical-align: middle` to make it works instead.

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'oswalditalic';
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 0;
}
ul{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    margin: auto; 
    border-spacing: 30px;
}


ul li{
    font-family: 'oswalditalic';
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:15px 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell; 
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
<h1>Choose</h1>
</header>

<ul>
    <li>Read a book and lay on bed the whole day</li>
    <li>Go outside and ride a bycicle with friends</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent. But when one circle has less text rows than the other, the one with the less slips down a little...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant the other code suggestion. But do you know how to get more space between the circles?

Comment: Since I change the display type of the ul element, you can use `border-spacing` to make some space (see updated snippet)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is due to the `line-height:300px`. The effect of this is that every line (also after word-wrapping) will occupy 300px. I see that you added this property to center your text. So if we remove the line we must find another way to accomplish the centering. Another possible way is to use a :before element and giving it a certain height.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'oswalditalic';
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  font-family: 'oswalditalic';
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 15px 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
ul li:before {
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Choose</h1>
  </header>

  <ul>
    <li>Read a book and lay on bed the whole day</li>
    <li>Go outside and ride a bicycle with friends</li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: It works fine with two lines, but what if you add a third or fourth line ? ;)

Comment: Then you could create a vertical alignment with a div using position relative and transform translateY. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sf3dquLs/3/). I don't like changing display of a li element to table-cell, it's just not made for that.

Comment: Thanks Rsauxil. Is it possible to get more space between the circles?

Comment: Sure, just add `margin-bottom:100px` to your ul li css (choose your own height).